# file path error (WINDOWS) with autotest growl ( REvised)

Tags: windows, rspec, autotest, growl

im going through the setup on 
http://www.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#fig:autotest_green

and im stuck on this particular error:

ERROR READOUT: http://pastie.org/1015405

What i can see being the tell-tale issue here is the

No such file or directory - Files/rubygems-1.3.7/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb

"Program Files" has been truncated to just "Files" and hence the programs cant find what its supposed to be looking for

READOUT of pages_controller_spec.rb: http://pastie.org/1015412

Comment: is this in Windows? The command line command you're using (sudo) appears to suggest you're on a Linux/Unix-like. Which one you're really in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SADLY i think this is what i didnt want to see:

https://rspec.lighthouseapp.com/projects/5645/tickets/711-autospec-fails-when-filepaths-include-spaces

Comment: Why not install ruby somewhere without spaces in directory names (c:\ruby). This works for me. Windows is certainly not the best choice for RoR, but it does work (autospec, rspec works here)

Comment: i just installed ubuntu hah!

im not really interested in troubleshooting tons of problems .. and i highly doubt that the problems were going to lessen :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it's an issue with a space in the filepath:

> c:/Program Files/rubygems-1.3.7/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controller s/pages_controller_spec.rb

Seems that is getting translated to

> Files/rubygems-1.3.7/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controller s/pages_controller_spec.rb

be sure to always place quotes around paths that contain a space ;)

Comment: Let me check this out ..it seems that my gitBASH console likes putting in spaces in the outputs.. for ex the "mtim e"

Turns out that was just spacing in the output of gitbash..not actually the file..but ill check it

Comment: while I know git-bash misbehaves like this in windows (hence I tend not to use it directly), the space in %PROGRAMS FILES% is their on just about every system that wasn't expressly pre-configured or altered to removed that space. A beer says thats the problem, hiding away. Other issue I was able to research have already been patched in the release you are trying to use.

Comment: SO i finally get what you're suggesting .. and it makes sense..<br />

`
'mtime' => lambda {|file_a, file_b| File.mtime(file_b) <=> File.mtime(file_a)}
`
<br />
the above code is what is contained on line 7 of the "options.rb"
<br />
i tried supstituting in single as well as double quotes in the following manners:
<br />
`
'mtime' => lambda {|"file_a", "file_b"| File.mtime("file_b") <=> File.mtime("file_a")}
`
<br />
and
<br />
`
'mtime' => lambda {|'file_a', file_b'| File.mtime('file_b') <=> File.mtime('file_a')}
`
both led to new/different errors soo thats now how to do it

Comment: another weird ass thing is the readout is

(tilde) mtime (single quote)

i feel like it should be 

(single quote)mtime(single quote)

Answer (score 0):

SO i finally get what you're suggesting .. and it makes sense..

`'mtime' => lambda {|file_a, file_b| File.mtime(file_b) <=> File.mtime(file_a)}`


the above code is what is contained on line 7 of the "options.rb"

i tried supstituting in single as well as double quotes in the following manners:

`'mtime' => lambda {|"file_a", "file_b"| File.mtime("file_b") <=> File.mtime("file_a")}`

and

`'mtime' => lambda {|'file_a', file_b'| File.mtime('file_b') <=> File.mtime('file_a')}`

both led to new/different errors soo thats now how to do it